# What does inherited mean in the context of class operators

Tags: delphi, operator-overloading, delphi-xe2

If I type out my record definition in the `interface` and then press <kbd>ctrl + alt + C</kbd>  Delphi fills out the following stub.

```
  class operator P<T>.GreaterThan(a, b: P<T>): Boolean;
  begin
    inherited;   <<-- ???

  end;
```

You cannot inherited from a record, to what does `inherited` in this context mean?

And Delphi is not even consistent:

interface:

```
class operator Implicit(a: pointer): P<T>; inline;
class operator Implicit(a: P<T>): pointer; inline;
class operator Implicit(Cell: TCell<T>): P<T>; inline;
class operator Implicit(P: P<T>): TCell<T>; inline;
```

implementation:

```
  class operator P<T>.Implicit(a: pointer): P<T>;
  begin  <<--- nothing
  end;

  class operator P<T>.Implicit(a: P<T>): pointer;
  begin
    inherited;  <<--  now you see it...
  end;

  class operator P<T>.Implicit(Cell: TCell<T>): P<T>;
  begin         <<-- now you don't
  end;

  class operator P<T>.Implicit(P: P<T>): TCell<T>;
  begin
  end;
```

I'm suspecting that Delphi takes one operator as "leading" (no inherited) and follows that implementation in the routines with `inherited` if it decides that the parameters are compatible.

**What does `inherited` in this context mean?**

<sub>Bonus questions</sub>
**What are rules does Delphi follow and what are pittfalls to look out for?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, `inherited` means nothing, since records cannot be inherited. The compiler ignores it and outputs no code. It looks like code completion is getting confused.

Comment: OK, I thought it had something to do with there being multiple overloaded versions of the same `class operator`.